# Galaxy Tab S2 Files showing on Mac - can't access them

Tags: samsung, mtp

We are trying to transfer some files from S2 Tablet to MacBook using AFT.

When we connect the tablet the files all show up on the MacBook but we can't access the files. At the same time we have Tablet file box on screen we also have the AFT error msg
"Can't access device storage". USB debugging on and MTP selected. The S2 shows up in the USB tree in system.

Any ideas as to how we can transfer the  files to MacBook?

Comment: .. what is AFT?

Comment: @alecxs I'd assume [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/)

Comment: doesn't look like a feature or app of android, this question is more suitable to https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/file-transfer+android